# Builder.put can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.work)

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-workmanager

When i am using **WorkManager** and I'm trying to pass some **object** to it

```
Data data = new Data.Builder().put("passstring",object).build();
```

getting me *Builder.put can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.work)* **error**

Answer (score 1):

You can use workDataOf() method. Just make sure you pass Pairs of data
eg.

```
workDataOf(Pair("param_name", "data"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should use `putString` method like this.

```
Data data = new Data.Builder().putString("passstring",object).build();
```

Because put method marked with annotation         `@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)` and not documented here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Data.Builder